# Put string in href="javascript" in append

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, append, href

I want to put a string into a href="javascript:" when i append a li but i doesn't work at all....

```
 ajoutEnf("myString");
 function ajoutEnf(enf){
   $('#laliste').append('<li><a href="javascript:popEnfant('+enf+')" data-icon="edit" data-rel="popup">Enfant</a></li>');
   $('#enf').popup('close');
   $('#laliste').listview('refresh');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will produce:

```
javascript:propEnfant(myString)
```

Thus clicking the link, the script will look for a variable named `myString`. You probably want to use `'<li><a href="javascript:popEnfant(\''+enf+'\')" ...`

Another thing to be aware of: if `popEnfant` is defined inside your `DOMReady` event listener (which I don't know if it is) it will not be globally accesible, which is a requirement for `javascript:...` to work.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/prTe8/)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the click event using jQuery.fn.on:

```
ajoutEnf("myString");
function ajoutEnf(enf){
    $('<a herf="#" data-icon="edit" data-rel="popup">Enfant</a>').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stop the hash from changing to "" (page.html#)
        popEnfant(enf);
     }).wrap('<li/>').parent().appendTo('#laliste');
     $('#enf').popup('close');
     $('#laliste').listview('refresh');
 }
```

This way you dont have to string whatever `enf` and make sure that objects/arrays are passed on correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do some little changes: add slashes with single quotes.

```
 $('#laliste').append('<li><a href="javascript:popEnfant(\''+enf+'\')" data-icon="edit" data-rel="popup">Enfant</a></li>');
```

Comment: This will fail horribly if `end == '">whoops</a><a href="'`

Comment: oops. sorry my mistake. it should be with single quote.